# Rest service number validation

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, service

I have a rest service in spring boot. I have a post method. In post method i accept json. It is working. But when client side send me a character for userId field(short), i take json parse error. Can i control this before exception? I want to customize error message but exception message is too complicated.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/customers", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<?> insertCustomer(@Valid @RequestBody InsertParams 
params)
/*
*/}

public class InsertParams() {
private Short userId;
}
```

Error message is: 
JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.lang.Short` from String "a": not a valid Short value

Comment: Your userId field is of type `long` but you're error says that a `String` can't be converted to **`Short`**? That doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: sorry my mistake, i fixed it

Comment: Does the request payload include the letter `a` as a `char`, or the decimal 97 (the ascii code for `a`) ? Based on your pojo and the way you've asked the question, I think the request payload should be `{"userId":97}`

Comment: Or are you asking how you can control the error message / exception handling when a request is received with invalid content? In which case, you could look at writing a `ControllerAdvice` class to handle the specific exception that is thrown (`JsonParseException` ?)

Comment: payload include a as a char and i get this error. i can handle exception in controller advice but message is too long and i dont know how to split it

Answer (score 0):

I did it this way.

```
@ExceptionHandler(HttpMessageNotReadableException.class)
public ResponseEntity<ExceptionResponse> 
handleHttpMessageNotReadable(HttpMessageNotReadableException ex) {

    String fieldName = "";

    String message = "";

    if (!(ex.getCause() instanceof JsonMappingException)) {
        return new ResponseEntity<ExceptionResponse>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }

    JsonMappingException e = (JsonMappingException) ex.getCause();

    for (JsonMappingException.Reference reference : e.getPath()) {
        fieldName = reference.getFieldName();
    }

    if (fieldName.toLowerCase().contains("date"))
        message = fieldName + " format exception. Should be yyyy-MM-dd";
    else
        message = fieldName + " can not take characters.";

    ExceptionResponse er = new ExceptionResponse();
    er.setResult("Failure");
    er.setStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.value());
    er.setDescription(message);

    return new ResponseEntity<ExceptionResponse>(er, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
```